# Place results of predict() in a for loop inside a list

Tags: r, for-loop, linear-regression

Let us say I want to run the linear regression model on the mtcars dataset several times on different samples.
The idea is, for each iteration in a for loop, to store the results of the predict() method every time the linear regression is run
for a different sample. The small example follows for one run:

```
## Perform model once on a Sample and use model on full dataset:
Sample_Size <- 10
Sample <- mtcars[sample(nrow(mtcars), Sample_Size), ]
 Model <- lm(formula = mpg ~ wt, data = Sample)
 Predictions <- predict(Model,newdata=mtcars)
 ## Gets us a list with predicted wt for each car:
Predictions <- t(Predictions)
```

This yields

```
> Predictions
     Mazda RX4 Mazda RX4 Wag Datsun 710 Hornet 4 Drive Hornet Sportabout
[1,]  25.80494      23.89161   28.05592       21.34051          19.65228
       Valiant Duster 360 Merc 240D Merc 230 Merc 280 Merc 280C Merc 450SE
 [1,] 19.50221   18.67685  21.52809 21.82822 19.65228  19.65228   14.92523
     Merc 450SL Merc 450SLC Cadillac Fleetwood Lincoln Continental
 [1,]   17.47633    17.10117           6.071394            4.765828

 .... and so on for other cars
```

I would like to perform this procedure several times inside a for loop, every time
choosing a different sample and getting a correspondent Predictions() list, 
and store all the Predictions() results by line in a dataframe.

Let's say I run the model for two different samples. Each row of the resulting dataframe should be the outcome above for that sample, like:

```
     Mazda RX4 Mazda RX4 Wag Datsun 710 Hornet 4 Drive Hornet Sportabout
 [1,]  25.80494      23.89161   28.05592       21.34051          19.65228
 [2,]  22.80492      22.89147   28.05532       21.34231          20.65290
       Valiant Duster 360 Merc 240D Merc 230 Merc 280 Merc 280C Merc 450SE
 [1,] 19.50221   18.67685  21.52809 21.82822 19.65228  19.65228   14.92523
 [2,] 21.83492   23.84147  29.02532 21.34231 20.35290  18.45228   13.92523

 ... and so on for other cars.
```

Any idea on how to go about doing this? I have developed something but it either
throws an error or only stores the last result...What am I missing here?

Here is what I have so far:

```
### Inside a for loop, to get a dataframe of Predictions:

Bootstrap_times <- 2
Sample_Size <- 10
Predictions <- list()
Results <-vector ("list",Bootstrap_times)## Stores the Predictions for each run

for(i in 1:Bootstrap_times){
### Take a sample
Sample[[i]] <- mtcars[sample(nrow(mtcars), Sample_Size), ]
### Do the regression on the sample
Model[[i]] <- lm(formula = mpg ~ wt, data = Sample[[i]])
### Perform the predict() on the sample
Predictions[[i]] <- predict(Model[[i]],newdata=mtcars)
### put the result as a line on the dataframe Results
Predictions[[i]] <- t(Predictions[[i]])
return(Predictions)
}
```

Howeever, I keep getting:

> Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = list(mpg = c(13.3,
>   10.4,  :  replacement has 10 rows, data has 0

Comment: thanks, I realized there is something missing, namely the Sample_Size parameter. Will add it now, cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to use `magic_for()` however you can also do this with base R pretty easily.

Here's an example:

```
Bootstrap_times <- 2
Sample_Size     <- 10

Sample      <- mtcars[sample(nrow(mtcars), Sample_Size), ]
Model       <- lm(formula = mpg ~ wt, data = Sample)
Predictions <- predict(Model,newdata=mtcars)
## You like how I line up arrows, right?
Predictions <- t(Predictions)


Predictions <- list()
Results     <-vector ("list",Bootstrap_times)## Stores the Predictions for each run

magicfor::magic_for()
for(i in 1:Bootstrap_times){
  ### Take a sample
  Sample[[i]] <- mtcars[sample(nrow(mtcars), Sample_Size), ]
  ### Do the regression on the sample
  Model[[i]] <- lm(formula = mpg ~ wt, data = Sample[[i]])
  ### Perform the predict() on the sample

  put(predict(Model[[i]],newdata=mtcars))
}

tmp<-magicfor::magic_result_as_dataframe()

tmp
```

> ```
>    i predict(Model[[i]],newdata=mtcars)
> 1  1                          22.858806
> 2  2                          20.922763
> 3  1                          25.136504
> 4  2                          18.341372
> 5  1                          16.633098
> 6  2                          16.481252
> 7  1                          15.646096
> 8  2                          18.531180
> 9  1                          18.834873
> 10 2                          16.633098
> 11 1                          16.633098
> 12 2                          11.849933
> 13 1                          14.431324
> 14 2                          14.051708
> 15 1                           2.890988
> 16 2                           1.569924
> 17 1                           2.169717
> 18 2                          26.047583
> 19 1                          30.489093
> 20 2                          28.818782
> 21 1                          24.035616
> 22 2                          16.025712
> 23 1                          16.671060
> 24 2                          13.596168
> 25 1                          13.558206
> 26 2                          28.059549
> 27 1                          26.503122
> 28 2                          31.263511
> 29 1                          18.683026
> 30 2                          21.719957
> 31 1                          15.646096
> 32 2                          21.644034
> 33 1                          22.978374
> 34 2                          21.584264
> 35 1                          24.618503
> 36 2                          19.725450
> 37 1                          18.495353
> 38 2                          18.386011
> 39 1                          17.784630
> 40 2                          19.862128
> 41 1                          20.080812
> 42 2                          18.495353
> 43 1                          18.495353
> 44 2                          15.051081
> 45 1                          16.909894
> 46 2                          16.636540
> 47 1                           8.599905
> 48 2                           7.648629
> 49 1                           8.080530
> 50 2                          25.274555
> 51 1                          28.472808
> 52 2                          27.270046
> 53 1                          23.825774
> 54 2                          18.057985
> 55 1                          18.522689
> 56 2                          16.308514
> 57 1                          16.281178
> 58 2                          26.723336
> 59 1                          25.602581
> 60 2                          29.030452
> 61 1                          19.971470
> 62 2                          22.158309
> 63 1                          17.784630
> 64 2                          22.103638
> ```

Comment: Thanks! I seem to be having trouble with the function magic_for()...are you sure your syntax is correct?

Comment: @Arrebimbomalho Yes, I'm sure. Can you show me what you ran and the error? You installed it first right? I'm guessing you need to install it with `install.packages()`. See also https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magicfor/index.html

Comment: Yes, I had to use githubinstall to get the library but it is done. I think I know whats missing, it is probably the declaration of Sample() and Model() as lists before the for cycle.

Comment: I just ran the code from your question before this. It produced the result above. I seem to be able to run it over any number of times and it still works. I will add the full code including your part

Comment: Bootstrap_times <- 2;
    Sample_Size <- 10;
    Predictions <- list();
    Results <-vector ("list",Bootstrap_times)#

    magicfor::magic_for();
    for(i in 1:Bootstrap_times){
      Sample[[i]] <- mtcars[sample(nrow(mtcars), Sample_Size), ];
      Model[[i]] <- lm(formula = mpg ~ wt, data = Sample[[i]]);
      put(predict(Model[[i]],newdata=mtcars));
    }
    magicfor::magic_result_as_dataframe();

Comment: to paste it all together in comment like that I'd need you to add the `;` so I can still run it. Can you try copying and pasting from my edited answer and let me know if that works for you?

Comment: Oop, sorry, first time pasting code in the comments. Live and learn I guess :) Cheers

Comment: Now it's working! Gr8! I put your code and straight up pasted it and it worked. Not to be pushy or anything, but do you know of any neat way to put the predictions of each run below the car name? :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: That probably comes by cutting the original dataframe at the 32 mark and then t(Dataframe) it...Not sure how to do it if the number of bootstraps is huge..Cheers!

Comment: @Arrebimbomalho You can put anything you want inside of `put`. like `put(prediction = predict(..pseudocode...), carnames = names(...), etc, etc`. Np. Cheers, good luck please remember to click the green checkmark :)

Answer (score 1):

My version:

```
# load data
data(mtcars)
N <- nrow(mtcars)

# bootstrap parameters
sample_size <- 10
bootstrap_times <- 20

# create empty storage matrix of results
# one row per bootstrap sample, one column per predicted weight
res_mat <- matrix(NA, nrow=bootstrap_times, ncol=N)
colnames(res_mat) <- rownames(mtcars)

# do bootstrap
for (i in seq(bootstrap_times)) {
    this_sample <- sample(N, sample_size, replace=FALSE)
    reg_result  <- lm(mpg ~ wt, data=mtcars[this_sample,])
    res_mat[i,] <- predict(reg_result, mtcars)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried your solution, but it seems to be filling the matrix only with NAs, it is not uodating the values for some reason

Comment: I think I know what it is...probably missing an index in reg_result inside the for_cycle. but how to declare it outside?

Comment: I just copy-pasted the above code into a fresh R session and I get the expected results -- sorry man, not sure what to tell you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` approach using nested data.frames:

```
library(tidyverse)

Bootstrap_times <- 2
Sample_Size <- 10

Predictions <- data.frame(SampleID = 1:Bootstrap_times) %>%
  group_by(SampleID) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(data = data %>% map(~mtcars[sample(nrow(mtcars), Sample_Size), ]),
         Model = data %>% map(~lm(formula = mpg ~ wt, data = .)),
         Predictions = map2(Model, data, ~predict(.x, newdata = .y))) %>%
  select(SampleID, Predictions) %>%
  unnest()
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 20 x 2
   SampleID Predictions
      <int>       <dbl>
 1        1        22.7
 2        1        16.2
 3        1        19.7
 4        1        21.5
 5        1        18.7
 6        1        17.4
 7        1        23.3
 8        1        10.7
 9        1        18.8
10        1        19.8
11        2        11.4
12        2        19.6
13        2        11.7
14        2        18.1
15        2        21.1
16        2        18.6
17        2        16.2
18        2        23.5
19        2        19.7
20        2        20.7
```

The advantage of this method is that it is very easy to extract other information from the model (using `broom`) and combine as one single data.frame output:

```
library(broom)

data.frame(SampleID = 1:Bootstrap_times) %>%
  group_by(SampleID) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(data = data %>% map(~mtcars[sample(nrow(mtcars), Sample_Size), ]),
         Model = data %>% map(~lm(formula = mpg ~ wt, data = .) %>% augment())) %>%
  select(-data) %>%
  unnest()
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 20 x 11
   SampleID .rownames            mpg    wt .fitted .se.fit .resid  .hat .sigma  .cooksd .std.resid
      <int> <chr>              <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>
 1        1 Dodge Challenger    15.5  3.52   17.2    0.689 -1.72  0.106   2.15 0.0442      -0.862 
 2        1 Datsun 710          22.8  2.32   23.5    0.940 -0.655 0.198   2.24 0.0148      -0.346 
 3        1 Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4  5.25    8.24   1.52   2.16  0.515   1.93 1.15         1.47  
 4        1 Merc 450SE          16.4  4.07   14.4    0.863  2.04  0.167   2.10 0.112        1.06  
 5        1 Ford Pantera L      15.8  3.17   19.0    0.672 -3.24  0.101   1.85 0.147       -1.62  
 6        1 Lotus Europa        30.4  1.51   27.6    1.39   2.75  0.432   1.79 1.14         1.73  
 7        1 Volvo 142E          21.4  2.78   21.1    0.751  0.334 0.126   2.26 0.00207      0.169 
 8        1 Merc 280C           17.8  3.44   17.6    0.678  0.163 0.103   2.26 0.000378     0.0812
 9        1 Mazda RX4 Wag       21    2.88   20.6    0.724  0.428 0.117   2.25 0.00308      0.215 
10        1 Camaro Z28          13.3  3.84   15.6    0.773 -2.26  0.134   2.06 0.102       -1.15  
11        2 Merc 280            19.2  3.44   19.7    1.09  -0.470 0.108   3.53 0.00138     -0.151 
12        2 Toyota Corolla      33.9  1.84   28.2    1.65   5.66  0.251   2.52 0.658        1.98  
13        2 Hornet Sportabout   18.7  3.44   19.7    1.09  -0.970 0.108   3.51 0.00588     -0.311 
14        2 Mazda RX4 Wag       21    2.88   22.7    1.07  -1.69  0.106   3.47 0.0173      -0.540 
15        2 Chrysler Imperial   14.7  5.34    9.50   2.42   5.20  0.539   2.02 3.15         2.32  
16        2 Camaro Z28          13.3  3.84   17.5    1.26  -4.23  0.145   3.08 0.163       -1.39  
17        2 Valiant             18.1  3.46   19.6    1.09  -1.46  0.110   3.48 0.0136      -0.469 
18        2 Porsche 914-2       26    2.14   26.6    1.43  -0.611 0.188   3.52 0.00490     -0.205 
19        2 Merc 280C           17.8  3.44   19.7    1.09  -1.87  0.108   3.45 0.0219      -0.600 
20        2 Lotus Europa        30.4  1.51   30.0    1.91   0.441 0.335   3.52 0.00677      0.164
```

**Note:**

Using this method, you don't even need the prediction step (unless you are using new data), since you have the `.fitted` values from `augment`.

The predictions are different between the first and second output because no seed was set.

Comment: Thanks! really in-depth answer, I appreciate it. Please leave it in so I can use it at a later stage :)