# Estimating multiple `lm` models and returning output in one table, with map()

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr, lm, stargazer

I need to estimate a number of linear models on the same dataset, and put the regression results all into one table. For a reproducible example, here's a simplification using `mtcars`:

```
formula_1 = "mpg ~ disp"
formula_2 = "mpg ~ log(disp)"
formula_3 = "mpg ~ disp + hp"
```

Currently, my approach has been to:

1. Create a list that contains all of the formulae.
2. use `purrr:map()` to estimate all of the `lm` models.
3. use `stargazer::` to produce output tables.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(stargazer)

formula_1 = "mpg ~ disp"
formula_2 = "mpg ~ log(disp)"
formula_3 = "mpg ~ disp + hp"

lst <- list(formula_1, formula_2, formula_3)
  
models<- lst %>% map(~lm(., mtcars))
stargazer(models, type = "text")
```

Which gives me the output I'm looking for:

```
#> 
#> =========================================================================================
#>                                              Dependent variable:                         
#>                     ---------------------------------------------------------------------
#>                                                      mpg                                 
#>                              (1)                     (2)                    (3)          
#> -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#> disp                      -0.041***                                      -0.030***       
#>                            (0.005)                                        (0.007)        
#>                                                                                          
#> log(disp)                                         -9.293***                              
#>                                                    (0.787)                               
#>                                                                                          
#> hp                                                                        -0.025*        
#>                                                                           (0.013)        
#>                                                                                          
#> Constant                  29.600***               69.205***              30.736***       
#>                            (1.230)                 (4.185)                (1.332)        
#>                                                                                          
#> -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#> Observations                  32                     32                      32          
#> R2                          0.718                   0.823                  0.748         
#> Adjusted R2                 0.709                   0.817                  0.731         
#> Residual Std. Error    3.251 (df = 30)         2.579 (df = 30)        3.127 (df = 29)    
#> F Statistic         76.513*** (df = 1; 30) 139.350*** (df = 1; 30) 43.095*** (df = 2; 29)
#> =========================================================================================
#> Note:                                                         *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

#### First Question:

How can I put all of the formulae into a list when there are many formula? The line below works if there are only 3 formulae, but seems clumsy when there are many models to be estimated.

```
lst <- list(formula_1, formula_2, formula_3)
```

#### Follow up Question:

Is there a better way to accomplish the entire task, using say `broom` or another method? Or is `purrr:map()` a reasonable solution?

Comment: You can put all the formulas in a tibble and then use `mutate(models = map(forumulas, ...)`. As far as generating all the formulas you could do some fancy work by building a function that takes your IV, DVs, and some modifying function and then pastes together a formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a workflow I would suggest. We can use nested `tibble`s to structure our data and use `broom` to get tidy estimates and fitted values:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

# Created nested tibble
nested_df <- tibble(formula = c("mpg ~ disp", "mpg ~ log(disp)", "mpg ~ disp + hp")) %>%
  group_by(ID = formula) %>%
  group_modify(~ as_tibble(mtcars)) %>%
  nest() 

# Get model estimates
nested_df %>%
  mutate(estimates = data %>% map2(ID, ~ tidy(lm(.y, data = .x)))) %>%
  select(-data) %>%
  unnest()

# Get fitted values and residuals
nested_df %>%
  mutate(model = ID %>% map2(data, lm),
         stats = model %>% map(augment)) %>%
  select(-data, -model) %>%
  unnest()
```

**Output:**

```
> nested_df
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  ID              data              
  <chr>           <list>            
1 mpg ~ disp      <tibble [32 x 11]>
2 mpg ~ disp + hp <tibble [32 x 11]>
3 mpg ~ log(disp) <tibble [32 x 11]>

# A tibble: 7 x 6
  ID              term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
  <chr>           <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1 mpg ~ disp      (Intercept)  29.6      1.23        24.1  3.58e-21
2 mpg ~ disp      disp         -0.0412   0.00471     -8.75 9.38e-10
3 mpg ~ disp + hp (Intercept)  30.7      1.33        23.1  3.26e-20
4 mpg ~ disp + hp disp         -0.0303   0.00740     -4.10 3.06e- 4
5 mpg ~ disp + hp hp           -0.0248   0.0134      -1.86 7.37e- 2
6 mpg ~ log(disp) (Intercept)  69.2      4.19        16.5  1.28e-16
7 mpg ~ log(disp) log(disp)    -9.29     0.787      -11.8  8.40e-13

# A tibble: 96 x 12
   ID           mpg  disp .fitted .se.fit .resid   .hat .sigma  .cooksd .std.resid    hp log.disp.
   <chr>      <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 mpg ~ disp  21    160     23.0   0.664 -2.01  0.0418   3.29 0.00865      -0.630    NA        NA
 2 mpg ~ disp  21    160     23.0   0.664 -2.01  0.0418   3.29 0.00865      -0.630    NA        NA
 3 mpg ~ disp  22.8  108     25.1   0.815 -2.35  0.0629   3.28 0.0187       -0.746    NA        NA
 4 mpg ~ disp  21.4  258     19.0   0.589  2.43  0.0328   3.27 0.00983       0.761    NA        NA
 5 mpg ~ disp  18.7  360     14.8   0.838  3.94  0.0663   3.22 0.0558        1.25     NA        NA
 6 mpg ~ disp  18.1  225     20.3   0.575 -2.23  0.0313   3.28 0.00782      -0.696    NA        NA
 7 mpg ~ disp  14.3  360     14.8   0.838 -0.462 0.0663   3.31 0.000770     -0.147    NA        NA
 8 mpg ~ disp  24.4  147.    23.6   0.698  0.846 0.0461   3.30 0.00172       0.267    NA        NA
 9 mpg ~ disp  22.8  141.    23.8   0.714 -0.997 0.0482   3.30 0.00250      -0.314    NA        NA
10 mpg ~ disp  19.2  168.    22.7   0.647 -3.49  0.0396   3.24 0.0248       -1.10     NA        NA
# ... with 86 more rows
```

If you prefer a `stargazer` table, we can also `pull` the `model` list-column out:

```
library(stargazer)

nested_df %>%
  mutate(model = ID %>% map2(data, ~ lm(.x, .y))) %>%
  pull(model) %>%
  stargazer(type = "text")
```

**Output:**

```
=========================================================================================
                                             Dependent variable:                         
                    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                     mpg                                 
                             (1)                    (2)                     (3)          
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
disp                      -0.041***              -0.030***                               
                           (0.005)                (0.007)                                

hp                                                -0.025*                                
                                                  (0.013)                                

log(disp)                                                                -9.293***       
                                                                          (0.787)        

Constant                  29.600***              30.736***               69.205***       
                           (1.230)                (1.332)                 (4.185)        

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Observations                  32                     32                     32           
R2                          0.718                  0.748                   0.823         
Adjusted R2                 0.709                  0.731                   0.817         
Residual Std. Error    3.251 (df = 30)        3.127 (df = 29)         2.579 (df = 30)    
F Statistic         76.513*** (df = 1; 30) 43.095*** (df = 2; 29) 139.350*** (df = 1; 30)
=========================================================================================
Note:                                                         *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

Note that `group_modify` is currently experimental, so please use with caution, as its properties and intent may likely change in the future.

Also see my other answer for a related problem: [Place results of predict() in a for loop inside a list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51430148/5150629)

Comment: This is great, a very neat example of how the current `group_modify()` can be useful.  Will be interesting to see what the core devs decide to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the formulas saved in your global environment, then you can make a list like this:

```r
formula_list<-do.call("list",mget(grep("formula",names(.GlobalEnv),value=TRUE)))
```

which gives you:

```r
#> $formula_1
#> [1] "mpg ~ disp"
#> 
#> $formula_2
#> [1] "mpg ~ log(disp)"
#> 
#> $formula_3
#> [1] "mpg ~ disp + hp"
```

I think using `purrr::map` is a good approach. But others may have better ideas.