# Creating a loop through a list of variables for an LM model in R

Tags: r, for-loop, linear-regression

I am trying to create multiple linear regression models from a list of variable combinations (I also have them separately as a data-frame if that is more useful!)

The list of variables looks like this:

```
Vars
x1+x2+x3
x1+x2+x4
x1+x2+x5
x1+x2+x6
x1+x2+x7
```

The loop I'm using looks like this:

```
for (i in 1:length(var_list)){
  lm(independent_variable ~ var_list[i],data = training_data)
  i+1
}
```

However it is not recognizing the string of `var_list[i]` which gives `x1+x2+x3` etc. as a model input.

Does any-one know how to fix it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57012832/5150629

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't even have to use loops. Apply should work nicely.

```
training_data <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:64), nrow = 8))
colnames(training_data) <- c("independent_variable", paste0("x", 1:7))

Vars <- as.list(c("x1+x2+x3",
                "x1+x2+x4",
                "x1+x2+x5",
                "x1+x2+x6",
                "x1+x2+x7"))

allModelsList <- lapply(paste("independent_variable ~", Vars), as.formula)
allModelsResults <- lapply(allModelsList, function(x) lm(x, data = training_data))
```

If you need models summaries you can add :

```
allModelsSummaries = lapply(allModelsResults, summary)
```

For example you can access the coefficient R² of the model `lm(independent_variable ~ x1+x2+x3)`  by doing this:

```
allModelsSummaries[[1]]$r.squared
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

We can create the formula with `paste`

```
out <- vector('list', length(var_list))

for (i in seq_along(var_list)){
  out[[i]] <- lm(paste('independent_variable',  '~', var_list[i]),
               data = training_data)
 }
```

Or otherwise, it can be done with `reformulate`

```
lm(reformulate(var_list[i], 'independent_variable'), data = training_data)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer.

For the first option it says: object independent_variable not found.

And for the second option it says: 'termlabels' must be a character vector of length at least one'.

Comment: @CL It is inside the `for` loop.  Also, I didn't get the last part of your mesage

Comment: I'm running the code in the same for loop as previously:
`
for (i in 1:length(var_list)){
  lm(paste(independent_variable, "~", var_list[i]),data = training_data)
  i+1
}
`

Comment: @CL I thought it is an object name. I guess, it shoould be quoted if it is a column name.  Updated the post

Comment: Perfect, it runs now but doesn't seem to produce any visible output. Is there something I'm missing? Thanks again for your help with this.

Comment: @CL You are not storing the output.  Please check the update

Comment: Brilliant it works really well. Thanks for the quick reply and helpful updates.